# Appending timestamp to command output

Tags: awk, sed

I run the following command:

```
sudo clustat | awk '/primary/ {print "{\"" $1 "\",\"server\":\"" $2 "\",\"status\":\""$3"\"}"}' |sed 's/\b:\b/":"/' >> test.log
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
{"service":"serviceA-primary","server":"serverA","status":"started"}
{"service":"service1-primary","server":"server1","status":"started"}
{"service":"service2-primary","server":"server2","status":"started"}
{"service":"service3-primary","server":"server3","status":"started"}
{"service":"service4-primary","server":"server4","status":"started"}
```

How do I append a timestamp to the beginning of each string? I tried different awk or sed command but I screw up my output.

i.e :

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMESTAMP=$(date -Is)

sudo clustat | awk -v TS="${TIMESTAMP}" ' '/primary/ {print "{"{\"timestamp\": \""TS"\", \"" $1 "\",\"server\":\"" $2 "\",\"status\":\""$3"\"}"}' |sed 's/\b:\b/":"/' >> test.log
```

The desired output would be:

```
{"timestamp": "2016-10-11T18:44:39+0000", "service":"serviceA-primary","server":"serverA","status":"started"}
{"timestamp": "2016-10-11T18:44:39+0000", "service":"service1-primary","server":"server1","status":"started"}
{"timestamp": "2016-10-11T18:44:39+0000", "service":"service2-primary","server":"server2","status":"started"}
{"timestamp": "2016-10-11T18:44:39+0000", "service":"service3-primary","server":"server3","status":"started"}
{"timestamp": "2016-10-11T18:44:39+0000", "service":"service4-primary","server":"server4","status":"started"}
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: "I tried different awk or sed command" --- edit your question to add one or more of those attempts! It's probably some small thing to fix it.

Comment: I edited my original post with an example of what I had tried.

Comment: Have a look at `ts`... http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it, just some quotes and backslashes that needed to be unscrambled.

I also replaced the sed command with a call to `sub` in the awk to keep everything in one command (also, since there's a `:` within the timestamp that you don't want to replace, it's actually simpler to do in the awk).

```
$ ... | awk -v TS="${TIMESTAMP}" '/primary/ {sub(":","\":\"",$1); print "{\"timestamp\":\""TS"\", \"" $1 "\",\"server\":\"" $2 "\",\"status\":\""$3"\"}"}'

{"timestamp":"2016-10-11T18:44:39+0000", "service":"nfssvc-primary","server":"clusternode2.example.com","status":"starting"}
```

Comment: I got:

    {"timestamp":"", "service":"service-primary","server":"server","status":"started"}

Comment: Did you set the TIMESTAMP variable? In your question you have `TIMESTAMP=$(date -Is)`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed I had commented it out. Thank you. The command works great.